# SendKeys not reliable with PDF loaded

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, sendkeys

I have a WebBrowser control in a WinForm app. I'm loading a PDF (using Adobe Reader XI) as such:

```
string url = Path.GetFullPath("test.pdf");
webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
```

Once this is loaded I am trying to use SendKeys to send the page down key from a button click:

```
webBrowser1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("{PGDN}");
```

This code works fine on a normal HTML page, but with the PDF loaded it has inconsistent behavior. Usually it only scrolls a page down every other click. Programmatically calling it twice doesn't seem to help.

```
webBrowser1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("{PGDN}");
webBrowser1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("{PGDN}");
```

I've also tried calling SendMessage with this code:

```
SendMessage(webBrowser1.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)VK_NEXT, (IntPtr)1);
SendMessage(webBrowser1.Handle, WM_KEYUP, (IntPtr)VK_NEXT, (IntPtr)1);
```

but this has no effect at all.

Can anyone suggest a solution to simulate the page down key press for the loaded PDF?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to show a particular page of the PDF you can [add a parameter to the URL](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) to specify the page. For example:

`webBrowser1.Navigate("http://somewhere.com/file.pdf#page=2")`

Comment: This was my first approach (I have a prev/next button) however if the person scrolls after loading the page I have no way to know which page is the previous or next page.